# inherit method to logger interface in log4j2 pkg

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, logging, log4j2

I have a method

```
     import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
     public class SendEmail
     {  
        Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();
        public static String getStackTrace(final Throwable throwable)
        {
           final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
           final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw, true);
           throwable.printStackTrace(pw);
           return sw.getBuffer().toString();
        } 
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
           //Some Code
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          log.error(getStackTrace(e));
        }
    }
   }
```

and I want to add getStackTrace() method to Logger by inheritance (Note : Logger is Interface not Class) so I can call it by log object so I can replace `log.error(getStackTrace(e))` ; by `log.error(log.getStackTrace(e))` ;
any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use `logger.error("message", exception)` but if you want your custom method you will need create your own class and keep the original logger inside. There is an error and debug methods, but if you need others you will need to create by yourself (like warn).

```
public class MyLogger {
    final Logger target;

    public MyLogger(Logger target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void error(Object message) {
        target.error(message);
    }

    public void debug(Object message) {
        target.debug(message);
    }

    //...

    public String getStackTrace(final Throwable throwable) {
        final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw, true);
        throwable.printStackTrace(pw);
        return sw.getBuffer().toString();
    }
}
```

In another class:

```
private static final MyLogger logger = new MyLogger(LogManager.getRootLogger());

public void someMethod() {
    try {
        //
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(logger.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the full stack trace info to string so I can show the exact exception .. with your solution it will get me just the following .. "log message NullPointer Exception " .. Sure I know what you want but sure I did it before

Comment: I edit my answer. This is the only way you will be able to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you very much .. the previous solution worked with me `log.error("Exception is :: ", ex);` I didn't notice the ',' .. but it works now .. and the edited one is good also but it is more headache .. Thank you :)